# Keep type information after hydrating a function

Tags: typescript, types, mapped-types

So, I have a bunch (hundreds) od dbMethods that are basically methods that take "db" as the first argument and then only turn to real methods. Later they are "hydrated" (the db is supplied), thus new methods are created.

My main problem is that I want the "hydrated" to be properly typed. Currently it's not, because reduce() loses type information. Do you have any suggestion? I'm sharing my attempts, but "RemoveFirstArgument" doesn't seem to be working.

```
const dbMethods = { // db is always the first argument
    getModerators: (db: any) => (chatId: string) => Promise.resolve([111]),
    getRooms: (db: any) => (accountId: string) => Promise.resolve([222])
}

type dbkeys = keyof typeof dbMethods

type WithDb = (db: any) => (...args: any) => any

type DbMethodContainer = {
  [key in dbkeys]: WithDb;
};

type RemoveFirstArgument<T = DbMethodContainer> = {
    [P in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[P]>;
};

// ultimately I want "hydrated" to have the right type
const hydrated: RemoveFirstArgument<typeof dbMethods> = Object.keys(dbMethods)
    .reduce((acc, method) => ({ ...acc, [method]: dbMethods[method](db) }), {})


// this is how I want to use it
const rooms = hydrated.getRooms('some accountId')
```

[Here's the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ssl=28&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgCYCMCyBTOALCSYIC8CA3ggPTnIoICWBAhgDYDuDAngThggGa0AneAgYCA5gFcAthihxQCRQjFY0eDAIZwIQgFwIAFKn0Mo7AJREAfIbDYtASST74A2lDGXCNgAoCIUvQYAHQCGDAQTABuGAYA2gCMSQC65gA0CkoqcABKEAEw%20kYoJmZeNgYMYJASck4ucG4e5Qh%20AUGh4ZEx8QBM-amgAL6goHDsAA48qADWGJxECHPsELwI41Or1Jg4eDCjIBs8AOq0OAAiNMTFpRbWhsGPomKFImX3puwHRwiXO7hIADC0DgDHcGkWJEycWWdCg1GWMGS%20lOFxQAG5hpiQGNJjwchgpBAYgAxQTwACC4mksjgAB4ACqLP5YAHAuRgqAaGzEKEgJQIOI%20OFLeZbBnIhAEuASARQBl4xlC5JWbFDbGgSgICRMOC0KRaDBMdgIBwINhyBAAImw7CQmjgGCQVvWEAQ9hi62wPDcYmwiCOoEgsEQtvthucUsJxIwZKEcCpkhkcjpRy2qH%20ex5CAA8igAFYYMBwYKI4qZ-DmTKKTpICRgWKVappBAyXZIFoGMiPYJVMAtuJtgGSjOsvaDsdIZLFSxDdKkOcHTVUHD0OgEXAsU3m0wBt0SGA8M5B6DCfwFRZhh1O4LZPIFAwAcgiMhE1QgtTgTkfVZxf6AA)

Comment: Is `dbMethods` type `X`?  Why don't you just create a class and pass it the `db`?

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, as plain text in the body of your post. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WGPKMw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values. (If you want to provide a playground link that's great, but please also put the full example in the body of the post as text.)